# How to make list of object's attributes and change it from list?

Tags: python

I want to make a list of an object's attributes and modify them from a list.

Something like:

```
class new_class():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

a = new_class(2)
b = [a.number]
b[0] = 1

# want it to be 1
print(a.number)
```

Comment: You can't really do that. `a.number` isn't a magic reference, it's just resolved to the value (2 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to store your instances in the list. There are other solutions that may require a designated class for your list, if you don't want to write `b[0].number`.
Storing the actual attribute in the list and changing the instance won't be possible, since you are storing variables of type int without any reference to the instance. You can however store an object containing a reference to the instance + the attribute, though I think storing the instance itself will be better.

```py
class new_class():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

a = new_class(2)
b = [a]
b[0].number = 1

# want it to be 1
print(a.number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the nearest we can do is this:

```
class new_class():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

a = new_class(2)
attrs = ['number']
def b(index, value):
    a.__dict__[attrs[index]] = value
b(0, 1)

# want it to be 1
print(a.number)
```